# Is it possible to add custom entries to the language switcher pointing to the same language?

Tags: i18n-l10n

I have a requirement to include Colombia, Peru and Mexico as part of the language switcher. Thing is these 3 countries all speak Spanish so is there a way to cater for this to include them in the language switcher? technically these three languages would have to point to the same spanish sub-domain

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use the [hook_language_switch_links_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!language.api.php/function/hook_language_switch_links_alter/7) to modify the output of the language switcher. I would try to create the needed entries there to maintain the functionality to switch languages properly.